# How to restore database from .pg_dump file using pgAdmin

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pg-restore

I was given a `mydb.pg_dump` file. I have created a new database test1 with pgAdmin. When I click right on the database and select `Restore...`, I can select my file after selecting "All files". But when I attempt to restore the database I immediately obtain this error:

> pg_restore: error: input file appears to be a text format dump. Please
>   use psql.

Can I use pgAdmin to restore a `.pg_dump` file? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use pgAdmin for that, because in a plain-text dump `COPY` statements are mixed with `COPY` data.

You need `psql` for that, which fortunately is already installed on your machine:

```
psql -d mydb -U postgres -f mydb.pg_dump
```